# How to scroll to a specific row in a specific page using Angular Material table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using angular material to display data in table with pagination, when the user clicks on a row, I redirect him to another page, and if he wants to go back to table page, he clicks on a button.

My problem is the user needs to go back to table page and to scroll to the specific row, I do it like this

```
document.getElementById(elementId).scrollIntoView()
```

but if the row clicked is not in the first page, the element is not found, how can I paginate to the page where the row exists ?

And the second problem is user can filter table then select a specific row, if I save the page number, when he will go back to table page, the data will be rendered without filter and the page number will not be correct

Answer (score 2):

you have to save the information about `pageIndex` when you go to another page, because when you come back your data table you have to give this index number to `[pageIndex]`. 
Ex:

```
<mat-paginator [length]="length"
          [pageSize]="pageSize"
          [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
          (page)="pageEvent = $event"
          [pageIndex]="pIndex">
</mat-paginator>
```

here `pIndex` is a variable that I define in my Component. if your `pageSize` is 10 and `pageIndex` is 0 then it show 1 to 10 row...

For more info: https://stackblitz.com/angular/ngdejmepgbr?file=app%2Fpaginator-configurable-example.html

Comment: but as I said if he sort the data then the user go to other page if he comes back, the page index is not the same, suppose the selected row is in pageIndex = 2,  he sort data, and the selected row is in pageIndex = 1, then he click on the row, when he will come back to the page, the selected item is back to page index 2, cause the sort is reset

Comment: you can save also the sort information and when user come back you can sort again if sort is true.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to know if there is another way without saving sort information

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect the paginator with Angular's router.

For example, let's say you structured your route path as follows:

```
http://my/url/to/table/component?page=2
```

In this case you can get the page index 2 from the url to the table as follow:

Component Class:

```
class MyComponent {

  pageIndex = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(
    map(params => params['page'])
  );

  constructor(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
}
```

Template:

```
<mat-paginator [pageIndex]="pageIndex | async"></mat-paginator>
```

So far the URL will drive the table. Now you also need to update the URL when the user navigates the table using the paginator:

Template:

```
<mat-paginator [pageIndex]="pageIndex | async" (page)="pageChange($event)"></mat-paginator>
```

Component Class:

```
class MyComponent {

  pageIndex = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(
    map(params => params['page'])
  )

  constructor(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, router: Router) {}

  pageChange(e: PageEvent): void {
    this.router.navigate( /* ... */ );
  }
}
```

Now that the URL is being updated as the user navigates around the table, that allows the router to then drive the table when the user returns to a previously visited URL.

Comment: but as I said if he sort the data then the user go to other page if he comes back, the page index is not the same, suppose the selected row is in pageIndex = 2, he sort data, and the selected row is in pageIndex = 1, then he click on the row, when he will come back to the page, the selected item is back to page index 2, cause the sort is reset

Comment: Also store the sorting information in the URL so that when the user returns they are presented with the same sorting configuration?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is not what I want, I am looking for another solution, you think is there another way to do it ?